# Testing equality of two instances of a class when they are typed as their base class and subclass?

Tags: c#, casting, equality

Lets say I have a high level interface `IRobot`

```
public interface IRobot
{
    Boolean DoAction(object action);
}
```

And two classes that implement this interface

```
public class WalkingRobot : IRobot
{
    public enum WalkAction { SLOW, FAST };
    public new Boolean DoAction(object inAction)
    {
        WalkAction action = (WalkAction)inAction;
        // Does the action based on argument
        return true;
    }
}

public class TalkingRobot : IRobot
{
    public enum TalkAction { ENGLISH, GERMAN };
    public new Boolean DoAction(object inAction)
    {
        TalkAction action = (TalkAction)inAction;
        // Does the action based on argument
        return true;
    }
}
```

If I then have a `List<IRobot>` that contain an instance of both of these classes

```
WalkingRobot walker = new WalkingRobot();
TalkingRobot talker = new TalkingRobot();
List<IRobot> robots = new List<>();
robots.Add(walker);
robots.Add(talker);
```

Will I be able to iterate over the `List<>` and compare each `IRobot` with my instances I have created?

```
WalkAction wAction = WalkAction.FAST;
TalkAction tAction = TalkAction.ENGLISH;
foreach(IRobot robot in robots)
{
    if(robot == walker)
        robot.DoAction((object)wAction);
    if(robot == talker)
        robot.DoAction((object)tAction);
}
```

Comment: You could use the `as` or `is` operators, but this defeats the purpose of using an interface in the first place.

Comment: Why are you specifying `new` in your `DoAction` method implementations?

Comment: `robot == walker` will do reference equality.  That would seem to work for this example.  Have you tried it?  If so, did it do what you wanted?

Comment: @JonSkeet I might have been confused. VS was given me some sort of warning when implementing a interfaces method in a class. I might have added it erroneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there's an `==` overload that you haven't shown, you're just comparing whether two references are equal - that's fine. You don't even need to cast `wAction` and `tAction` to `object`, as you can just use the implicit conversion:

```
foreach(IRobot robot in robots)
{
    if (robot == walker)
    {
        robot.DoAction(wAction);
    }
    else if (robot == talker)
    {
        robot.DoAction(tAction);
    }
}
```

That will work, but overall this isn't great object-oriented design by a long way. You're not the robots in the same way, and each robot has to cast their action to the right type.

If this is *just* meant to be a question about comparing objects with `==`, that's fine - but I would steer away from the rest of the code in terms of a design.

Comment: Sorry, I just caught my error in the example code I gave. I didn't mean to specify a `Type` there, I meant to check the equality against the instances of the classes themselves. I have made an edit to the OP. // I want to check if the given `IRobot robot` is either the `walker` or `talker`.

Comment: Thank you, and yes. I am trying to get away from this design. Basically I want to pass around `IRobot`s and call their `DoAction`s and supply parameters. But if each parameter is a different type it seems difficult? It that makes sense?

Comment: @KDecker: Well it's tricky because we don't know what you're trying to achieve in a wider context. You might want to make `IRobot` generic in the type of its action parameter... or you might not. It depends on the context.

Comment: Hmm, that actually might just do the trick. I hadn't thought of that. // Too much context. // Thank you for the help.